# How to suppress (only) warning "Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0:"

Tags: ffmpeg

When I am converting a *.mp4 video files with command line ffmpeg and 2-pass h264 codec then occasionally many lines similar to the following warning appear:

[libx264 @ 0000026e183ad900] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[null @ 0000026e18972440] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 7 >= 7

As I read, errors like this are silently auto-fixed by ffmpeg during conversion. Good.

Since I don't have to care about them I want to suppress the output of these warning.
And ONLY these warnings! All other should be shown as before.

How can I achieve this for command line ffmpeg command?

Comment: Add -`enc_time_base -1` to the 1st pass.

Answer (score 0):

According to the post
[FFmpeg - What does non monotonically increasing dts mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231348/ffmpeg-what-does-non-monotonically-increasing-dts-mean)

> This message is not about the input file's validity, it is from the output format not accepting non monotonous dts

You may either try another output format, or you will need to patch ffmpeg
and compile from source.

You will need to add the AVFMT_TS_NONSTRICT flag to the
[nullenc.c file](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/ce8f77a903e1108bde774d5e0e59d8cd24f18c46/libavformat/nullenc.c#L36)
so the line looks like:

```
  .flags = AVFMT_TS_NONSTRICT | AVFMT_VARIABLE_FPS | AVFMT_NOFILE | AVFMT_NOTIMESTAMPS,
```

In 2015 a
[patch](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2015-January/167811.html)
was submitted to add the flag to `nullenc.c`, but was never merged.

Comment: Considering I'm getting this from an output format of 'copy' as well as 'null' when simply counting frames using FFMPEG, I'm guessing that this isn't entirely accurate.

Comment: @psouza4 in the link provided in the answer it says that ffmpeg does the DTS check even for formats that doesn't need it, therefore it spams warnings.